# How to make a connection wait in a non blocking way in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm curious about node.js and I spend a couple of hours on reading and watching video. I didn't write that much code but I have an unexpected behavior on the few lines I wrote :

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
      res.write('Wait some seconds please<br/>');

      setTimeout(function() {
       res.end("I'm done");   
      }, 10 * 1000);
}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

When there's an incoming request this code is supposed :

1. Write on the output the first line
2. Asking node to call a function after ten seconds, then make the browser wait
3. Write the second line and returning.

Thus I assumed that if I called the server with another browser while a first request was pending I get a new request to process in parallel with the first one.

But the server is not responding and then the second browser just wait until the first request is done to get its content from the server. I then assume that setTimeout is blocking. How can I achieve the goal first described above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node Js problems with response.write](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068820/node-js-problems-with-response-write)

Comment: Your code seems to suffer from the same issue as that question - it is browser-specific whether or not you get the response in chunks.

Comment: I see the written data, I'm quite sure about what I wrote the Firefox's waiting animated item isn't the same while trying to connect and while waiting a server answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that browsers have a limit on the number of cuncurrent requests. You could try doing the same with one request from IE and one from Firefox or so, and I'm sure it will work. I'm sure that this is not a nodejs issue.

Comment: Ok, my code my correct, it was Firefox that's blocking multiple request send from to the same resources. Thanks !