# Passing streaming of Http response to a web page using node.js

Tags: node.js, cross-browser

Following up on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751711/streaming-http-responses-with-nodejs/9751949#comment12483738_9751949) I was wondering is there is a way, without using socket.io, to avoid the buffering of the response that happens on most navigators. So for instance if the node server emit every 5 secondes : 'hello world' i can directly print them on a webpage as soon as the data is available.

Is there a way to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not how web browsers work. If you want this type of functionality without using WebSockets (or a socket.io fallback) you could try with [Server-Sent Events](http://dev.w3.org/html5/eventsource/). See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/1560654) for an example (in coffeescript). Also, [here is a polyfill](https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource) for older browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the links linus, i ll invetigate these options and see what ends up fitting best.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is doable.  This is how [comet streaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29#Streaming) servers work.

See http://faye.jcoglan.com/ for an example for Node.js.

Comment: Thanks this looks a lot like what i would need, are you by anychance aware of a PHP equivalent ?

Comment: Not specifically.  Googling "php comet server" has a few results, and also turns up this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603201/using-comet-with-php).