# Impossible for Browsers to Peek at XHR.responseText?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

The most relavent post I saw was: [Streaming Http responses with NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751711/streaming-http-responses-with-nodejs)

Just to verify with others here, there is no longer any way from a browser to access the **xhr.responseText** before it is completed, right?

If impossible, I will just have to make all clients poll like 20 times a second or something.

**Node.js server part**

```
app.get('/peek', function(request, response) {
    console.log('   Client Connected');
    response.write('o');
    response.write('hai');
    response.write('der');
    response.end();
    setTimeout(function() { // Delay a bit
        response.writeContinue();
        response.write(' bear');
        response.end();
    }, 250);
}
```

**Client JavaScript part**

```
oReq.onreadystatechange=function() {
    switch(this.readyState) {
        case 1:
            ptr=this;
            console.log('Opened: ');
            break;
        case 2:
            console.log('Header Recieved: '+this.status);
            break;
        case 3:
            console.log('Loading: '+this.status);
            break;
        case 4:
            console.log('Recieved: '+this.status);
            break;
    }
    if(2<this.readyState) console.log(this.responseText);
}
```

Comment: There's an example at the beginning of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest  . It looks similar to what you are doing here.

Comment: Sounds like you need websockets. 20 times a second is just not feasible with xhr.

Comment: If websockets aren't an option, long-polling might be.  You can get very low latency that way (polling will likely be 1-2 seconds at best, and that will hit your servers pretty hard).  If you give more information about your problem, we will be better able to help you.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789703/how-to-write-javascript-in-client-side-to-receive-and-parse-chunked-response-i

Comment: long-polling would be worse if you want split-second responses frequently. You want it realtime go with websockets.

Comment: haha yeah, I didn't wanna resort to polling super fast. It is going to be a small game server.  I am bout to do a hackathon with some friends. Getting some practice with Node.js before hand.

Comment: @bfavaretto Since I am coding for a browser, there is no ability to access the data when streaming. I tried something like that already.