# SSE and NodeJS Express

Tags: javascript, node.js

Cannot get SSE events to file in browser.

This the server code (express):

```
app.all('/callme', function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Connection': 'keep-alive',
      'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    });

    setInterval(function(){
      console.log('writing');
      res.write((new Date()).toString() + '\n');
    }, 1000);
})
```

This the client code:

```
var source = new EventSource('/events');
source.onmessage = function(e) {
      document.body.innerHTML += e.data + '<br>';
};
```

I use this same server code using XHR on the client and it works.  The server appears to be sending the data correctly, but not getting fired in the browser..

**I've already read [JavaScript EventSource SSE not firing in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978466/javascript-eventsource-sse-not-firing-in-browser)**  Doesn't seem to apply here, as I'm not running anti-virus that would affect it.

Comment: just the naming convention I use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the formatting on your event isn't correct

You want it formatted like this

```
res.write("id: " + Date.now() + "\ndata: " + message + "\n\n");
```

---

Also, check out this

[node-easysse](https://github.com/mosdefbiz/node-easysse) and [easysse-client](https://github.com/mosdefbiz/easysse-client)